# New Instance of UserPrincipal(PrincipalContext) Returns Null

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have this little snippet of code in a contructor:

```
public class ADUser : ADObject
{
    public ADUser(PrincipalContext ouContext)
                : base(null)
    {
         ou = ouContext;
         // Even after instantiating, user remains null, which is where the problem lies.
         user = new UserPrincipal(ouContext);
         base.principal = user;
    }
}

public abstract class ADObject
{
    protected Principal principal;
    protected PrincipalContext ou;

    public ADObject(Principal principal)
    {
        this.principal = principal;
    }
}
```

`ou` is a protected variable in the base class that stores the `PrincipalContext` of the AD OU of the AD user being modified or created.

When debugging, the parameter `ouContext` is *not* a null value, yet every time I try to instantiate a new UserPrincipal object with it as the parameter, `user` always ends up being null.

Here is the output of the ouContext PrincipalContext object:

```
-ou {System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext}   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext
        ConnectedServer "CensoredDC02.CensoredDomain.CensoredParentDomain.com"  string
        Container   "OU=Censored,OU=Censored2,DC=CensoredDomain,DC=CensoredParentDomain,DC=com" string
        ContextType Domain  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType
        Name    "CensoredDomain"    string
        Options Negotiate | Signing | Sealing   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions
        UserName    null    string
```

The PrincipalContext object is created in another class using this code:

```
/* baseDomain has the FQDN the OU is in, and ouSelection contains the full DN path of the OU. */
ouContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, baseDomain, ouSelection.SelectedValue.ToString());
/* Then a new ADUser object is created... */
ADUser user = new ADUser(ouContext);
/* Shortly after, the null value returned by new UserPrincipal(ouContext) causes an exception to be thrown in another function. */
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There's not quite enough context here.  Please include enough source code to reproduce the problem.  Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: What do you mean?  There is "context" all over that post! :)

Joking aside, I'm not sure what else to add.  Shortly after ouContext is created, new ADUser(ouContext) is called, and then new UserPrincipal(ouContext) returns a null value.  I'll add that to the post for clarity.

Comment: There's still not enough code here to compile and run, so you'll get guesses instead of answers.  Constructors cannot return null values, so there is a problem in code that you have not yet provided.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: You've done it!  You've cleared the cobwebs away!  That was the missing link; the instantiation wasn't actually returning null, the object contained null values that I was working with later on in the code.  The way that Visual Studio presented the information made it appear as if the object was actually null.  So easy to get blinded by a problem that doesn't actually exist... :)